# jquery check if a div is clicked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="gridStage">
   <div id="point1" class="point rounded-corners">
   </div>
</div>
```

#gridStage is a larger div inside which a smaller div #point is contained.

**I want to call a correct function if a user clicks on `#point` and another wrong function if the user clicks anywhere on `#gridStage` but not on `#point`.**

**The problem is that when the user clicks on `#point`, jQuery also detects click on `#gridStage` as a result of which both the functions are called, which is not required.**

Currently I am able to do it with the following code:

```
var pointClick=0;
$(".point").click(function() {
var pointClick=1;
    correct();
    setTimeout(function() {
       pointClick=0;
    },1000);
});
$("#gridStage").click(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
       if(pointClick===0) {
           wrong();
       }
    }, 500);
});
```

But I know **this is an inefficient way**, so is there any other good solution possible??

**Note:** All I want to do is that I have a grid as an image, then I overlay a div over it & I want to detect if a user has clicked a correct point or not for which I place a div on the correct point on top of the overlay grid, now I have to detect whether his click is on correct point or noyt. So if you have a better layout for this except the above which I am using, you are free to suggest so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation.

```
$(".point").click(function(e) {
    correct();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#gridStage").click(function() {
    wrong();
});
```

(note the `e` parameter on the line `$(".point").click(function(e) {` and the `e.stopPropagation();`)